# Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality error in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get document which lies between two dates that is `sem_start_date` and `sem_end_date`:

[image]

This is my code of getting values from firebase

```
getTestFeeStructure() async {
  feeTestModelList.clear();
  feeTestNameList.clear();
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('feeStructureTest')
      .where('sem_start_date',isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:'21-05-2023')
      .where('sem_end_date',isLessThanOrEqualTo:'21-05-2023')
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      FeeTestModel feeModel = FeeTestModel(
        documentId: doc.id,
        feeName: doc["fee_name"],
        amount: doc["amount"],
        academicYear: doc["academic_year"],
        courseName: doc["course_name"],
        customFeeName: doc["custom_fee_name"],
        semId: doc["sem_id"],
        semStartDate:doc["sem_start_date"],
        semEndDate:doc["sem_end_date"],
      );
      feeTestModelList.add(feeModel);
      feeTestNameList.add(feeModel.feeName);
    }
    isLoading = false;
    update();
  });
}
```

I am getting error given below in image. Is there any way to get values

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear: all relational conditions (`>`, `<`, etc) in a query in Firestore must be in the same field. There is no way in a Firestore query to perform such conditions across multiple fields.

From the Firestore documentation on its [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So you'll have to change this query to work around this limitation, most commonly by having one relational condition in the query and performing the rest of the filtering in your application code.

Also see:

- [Firestore compound query with <= & >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065946/firestore-compound-query-with)
- [All where filters with an inequality (Firestore - Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017250/all-where-filters-with-an-inequality-firestore-java)
- [Firebase Query Error: hasInequality == field': All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931396/firebase-query-error-hasinequality-field-all-where-filters-with-an-inequal)